# Processing the data returned by PHP for an AJAX call in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My PHP script

```
<?php
//connect to server
//selecting the database
$temparr=array();
$count=0
$result = mysql_query("some query");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $temparr["$count"]= $row["value"] ;
   $count+=1;
}
echo json_encode($temparr);
mysql_close($conn); 
?>
```

The AJAX function call in my javascript file is as follows

```
function someFunction(){

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "mymethodpath", true);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //this gives me a popup of the encoded data returned by the php script
        // the format i see in the popup window is ["1","2"]
        var temp=$.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

        alert(temp.count);
        //however this produces an undefined value

     }

  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

So how do i parse the string returned and display the correct count (here count should be 2)

Comment: i am populating $temparr in the while loop in the php script.

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). BTW, if you're using jQuery, why not use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

Comment: use  obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); also consider to remove $ in the key for `$temparr["$count"]` ...

Comment: Then you can directly use `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. No need for `$count` variable..

Comment: @MarcelKorpel i am relatively new to jQuery so am not familiar with the $.getJSON so will read up on that and see if it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want the number of elements in the returned array. However, `count` is not the proper JavaScript property. Use `temp.length` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct method:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('["1","2"]');
alert(obj.length);
```

".count" needs to be replaced by ".length".
Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rrYz/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can simplify your ajax call btw:

```
function someFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "mymethodpath",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            alert(jsonObj.length);
        }
    });
}
```

You could also use `$.getJSON()` but I myself like to stay with the basic function (which getJSON would use too behind the scenes).

Comment: thanks! I am relatively new to jQuery so will read up on your tweak!

Answer (score 0):

Call your php script in the browser window and you will see that you have no JSON object called "count". your array will consist of elements labelled 0, 1, 2, ...

If you try displaying temp[0] you should see your first value.